# Copy TYPO3 to a new domain

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I try to copy a TYPO3 installtion to a new directory (and new domain), but got some problems I can't figure out where they come from.

What I have done is: I copied all the files to the new directory (New domain is mapped to this directory). I copied the database. I changed the DB Logininfos in typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php.

When I call the new domain now I get `Oops, an error occurred!`. So far so good (I will have to change the domains in the backend else it can't work).

When I want to login in the backend (/typo3) I get the login-mask, but without any CSS or images. I also can't login, it says user or passwort is wrong. I changed the admin-password in the new database but still can't login.

I am not sure what I can do now or how I can debug whats wrong.

To the CSS and Images:
Both /typo3 Sites include the same CSS `/typo3temp/compressor/merged-XXXX.css?xxxx`. But the version on the copied version is muuch shorter.

Then the image

```
//Version on original:
<img src="sysext/t3skin/images/login/typo3logo-white-greyback.gif" alt="" class="t3-login-logo">
//Version on copied-version
<img src="../skin/images/login/typo3logo-white-greyback.gif" alt="" class="t3-login-logo">
```

Do I miss something? How could I find my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

empty the typo3temp folder did the trick.